# Where is the official new Ubuntu release feature list?

Tags: release-management, systemd

I tried to find the official feature list of new Ubuntu release. Could not find it with my favorite search engine and not in the [Ubuntu-wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/).

I want to see if systemd is included. I could find a lot of blog posts about it, but not an official feature list or roadmap.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [Ubuntu future release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) and it's Not yet support on ASK Ubuntu.

Comment: @KasiyA I think this is fine - it's not asking for support or anything. On top of that, this can apply to any new version, not just 15.04.

Answer (score 8):

- There is no official features list as of yet for 15.04.
- Debian plan to integrate systemd as default in their 8.0 release (codenamed ‘jessie’) and this release has not got a release date yet.
- Since work on 15.04 already started I would expect systemd not to be included in 15.04 (for 15.04 to have systemd I would expect 'jessie' to be ready).
- For that matter I would expect 15.10 to still have upstart with an extra installer to replace it with systemd where 16.04 would have systemd as default.

Answer (score 7):

For each new release there is a cycle of definition then freeze of features that will or will not be included. Anything discussed before that date is premature and may change.

Usually [Feature Definition Freeze](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FeatureDefinitionFreeze) will be some weeks after uploading the toolchain followed by a definite [Feature Freeze](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FeatureFreeze) approx. 2 months before the final release.

The schedule for the next version is not yet published but you may have a look at the schedule from the last release ([Utopic Unicorn release schedule](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UtopicUnicorn/ReleaseSchedule)) to get an idea.

This is why at present there will be not yet be any "official" feature list.